# java iterator hasnext method works unusual

Tags: java, database, iterator

I use an iterator to go through list of Entry objects.It goes through the iterator, and initialize a preparedStatement Object and add the object to batch. when the batch reached a specific size, it executes the batch and do the operation again.
 here's a part of my code:

```
for (Fields field : fieldList) 
{
            if(field != null)
            {
                if (countField < batchLimit)//check if the batch size limit is reached 
                {
                    //more items can be added to batch
                    Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> i = field.getParameters();
                    if (i != null) 
                    {
                        while (i.hasNext()) 
                        {
                            Entry<String, List<String>> e = i.next();
                            for (String str : (List<String>) e.getValue()) 
                            {
                                psField.setString(1, field.getField1());
                                psField.setString(2, field.getField2());
                                psField.setString(3, str);
                                psField.addBatch();//add record to batch
                                psFieldTemp.addBatch();
                                countField++;
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
                else 
                {
                    //records in batch will be executed to Database
                    psField.executeBatch();
                    psFieldTemp.executeBatch();
                    countField = 0;
                    //empty the batch
                    psField.clearBatch();
                    psFieldTemp.clearBatch();
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is: Whenever iterator has two different entries with the same value from `field.getParameters()`, the codes doesn't proceed from this line:

```
while(i.hasnext())
```

For example, if values taken from two different entries in iterator is like `"language=java"`, for the first entry, codes pass while condition but for the second entry it doesn't.
I fixed the problem using Map, but I want to know why this happens.

EDIT: I added more piece of code.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to give an [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions). Also verify the language you are using. You are asking about *Java* iterators and your question is tagged *JavaScript*.

Comment: @Axel My code is in java. I think the tag is ok. what other piece of code you think is necessary? I wrote the part The problem comes from and also brought an example from debug time.

Comment: The tag was changed to Java. It would really help if you provided the shortest compilabe example (preferably a class with a `main` method and the input that produces the error you describe). In the current form, one can only guess that you are trying to add two entries with the same key into a map (which will not work because the second one will overwrite the first).

Comment: yeah right! I'm just wondering how you fixed the problem using Map!

Comment: @Axel I changed the code and more piece of piece with a bit more explnation about what I want to do.

Comment: @Pazis question has been edited.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a second set of entries? Maybe it does not go further because there are no sets of entries left. You should debug to verify that too.